# Splitting the String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
Var FullName = John, Cooper;
```

Where `LastName = John and FirstName = Cooper`.

How can i split the string FullName and display my two TextField values with LastName and FirstName.

```
FullName.split(","2);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem (apart from syntax errors)? You know already `split` so where are you stuck? If you don't know how to use it, [look at some examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, strings in JavaScript have a `"` before and after it. Second, it is `var` and not `Var`.

Say you have

```
var FullName = "John, Cooper";
```

Then you can code like this to split:

```
var FirstName = FullName.split(", ")[1];
var LastName  = FullName.split(", ")[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var splitted = "john, cooper".split(', '),
    lastName = splitted[0],
    firstName = splitted[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because I like the pattern:

```
var fullname = "John, Cooper";

(function(first, last) {
    console.log(first, last);
}).apply(null, fullname.split(/,\s*/));
```

**explanation**:

The above code creates a `function expression` (that is done by wrapping the function into the parenthesis). After that it self-invokes that created function immediately by calling `.apply()` from the `Function object` (remember, most things in ECMAscript are objects, so are functions). Any function inherits from `Function` and the `.apply()` method takes two arguments. 1. a context (=object) for the `this` parameter in the invoked method and 2. an argumentslist as `Array`. Since `.split()` returns an `Array` we use that to directly pass the result from `.split()` as arguments.

Comment: That's an interesting way, although the first and last name are swapped in the questiom.

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing and why someone would use this type of pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
Var FullName = 'John, Cooper';
name   =  FullName.split(',');
name[0]---//Jhon;
name[1]----//cooper
console.log(FullName.split(','));
```

Comment: Yes, `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: dude i got perfectly as said,,   wat browser u use...<<<

Comment: Chrome, which browser that supports `Var` and `---` do you use?